# how to get 3 boolean values from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have data frame of integer values 0 t0 100.
and I want to classify these values into 3 parts, **low**, **mid** and **high** with low being less than 33, high being greater than 66 and mid is in between 33 and 66.
So I use

```
df['low'] = df['int'] <= 33
df['mid'] = 33  < df['int'] < 66
df['high'] = df['int'] >= 66
```

and i get error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_12080/1299746928.py in <module>
      1 df['low'] = df['int'] <= 33
----> 2 df['mid'] = 33  < df['int'] < 66
      3 df['high'] = df['int'] >= 66

c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1536     def __nonzero__(self):
   1537         raise ValueError(
-> 1538             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1539             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1540         )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I have alredy tried if else statement and also `and` and other operator.
low and high works, but the mid doesn't work.

please can I know any way around?

Comment: Use the [between](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) function: `df['int'].between(33, 66)`

Comment: Use the between function: df['int'].between(33, 66). This works bro. Thanks for the answer. I will edit my post.

Comment: `df['mid'] = (33 < df['int']) & (df['int'] < 66)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you get in comments you can use `between(33, 66)`

```
df['mid'] = df['int'].between(33, 66)
```

But you can write it also as

```
df['mid'] = (33 < df['int']) & (df['int'] < 66)
```

You could also use `(not low) and (not high)`

```
df['mid'] = ~df['low'] & ~df['high']
```

---

Minimal working example

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'int': range(0, 100, 10), 
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
 
df['low'] = df['int'] <= 33
df['high'] = df['int'] >= 66

df['mid1'] = (33 < df['int']) & (df['int'] < 66)

df['mid2'] = ~df['low'] & ~df['high']

df['mid-between'] = df['int'].between(33, 66)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
   int    low   high   mid1   mid2  mid-between
0    0   True  False  False  False        False
1   10   True  False  False  False        False
2   20   True  False  False  False        False
3   30   True  False  False  False        False
4   40  False  False   True   True         True
5   50  False  False   True   True         True
6   60  False  False   True   True         True
7   70  False   True  False  False        False
8   80  False   True  False  False        False
9   90  False   True  False  False        False
```

---

**BTW:**

If you use [pandas.cut()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html)

```
bins =  pd.cut(df['int'], [-1, 33, 66, 100], labels=['low', 'mid', 'high']) 

print( bins )
```

then you can get

```
0     low
1     low
2     low
3     low
4     mid
5     mid
6     mid
7    high
8    high
9    high
```

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'int': range(0, 100, 10), 
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

min_value = min(df['int']) - 1
max_value = max(df['int']) + 1

bins = pd.cut(df['int'], [min_value, 33, 66, max_value], labels=['low', 'mid', 'high'])

print(bins)
```

but it rather works as `open-close` range (in math `(a, b]`):

```
min < x <= 33
 33 < x <= 66
 66 < x <= max
```